# How to separate implementation signature from overload signature

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm looking for a way to separate a function implementation signature from its overload signatures. All examples I could find put the overload and implementation signature in one file. But I need to separate them since I want to generate the overload signatures based on some other code.

Let's say I have index.ts

```js
function saySomething(sayThis: string | number) {
  console.log(sayThis);
}
```

and another file types.ts

```js
declare function saySomething(sayThis: 'hello'): 'hello';
declare function saySomething(sayThis: 'goodby'): 'goodby';
declare function saySomething(sayThis: string): string;
declare function saySomething(sayThis: number): number;
```

With this setup typescript at least applies the overloads. But it shows the following error: `Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.(2384)`. So I assume the problem is the `declare` keyword, which should be used only if there is no acutal implementation within the module (as far as I understood). But if I use export instead, typescript complains that the implementation signature is missing.

Comment: For now I changed the file extension where the saySomething method is implemented to .js and the typescript compiler seems to be fine with this. Although this is not an ideal solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function type and assign your function to a constant with this type:

```ts
type SaySomething = {
    (sayThis: 'hello'): 'hello';
    (sayThis: 'goodby'): 'goodby';
    (sayThis: string): string;
    (sayThis: number): number;
}

const saySomething: SaySomething = function saySomething<T extends string | number>(sayThis: T): T {
  console.log(sayThis);
  return sayThis
}
```

Note that in your case you need to use a generic function because the return type depends on the parameter type.

Another possibility is to use a type assertion (you lost type safety):

```ts
const saySomething = function saySomething(sayThis: string | number): string | number {
  console.log(sayThis);
  return sayThis
} as SaySomething
```

To define the function type, you can also use a union:

```ts
type SaySomething =
    | ((sayThis: 'hello') => 'hello')
    | ((sayThis: 'goodby') => 'goodby')
    | ((sayThis: string) => string)
    | ((sayThis: number) => number)
```

By the way, I am not sure to understand your use case. A generic function could be enough:

```ts
function saySomething<T extends string | number>(sayThis: T): T {
  console.log(sayThis);
  return sayThis
}
```